# Fullcalendar how to remove padding from events in timegridview?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I need to remove the padding from an event when the calendar is in 'timegridview'.  My users are clicking in the empty space created, allowing them to get around a time slot that should be blocked.

I have it set so that on event click, it shows the event details.

For example, if I have an event from 11am to noon blocked for 'Lunch', users are clicking in the empty space which then brings up the scheduling dialog.

[image]

I've tried this CSS snippet which takes care of the spacing on the left and right, but I can't top/bottom.

```
.fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset {
        left: -8% !important;
        right: -8% !important;
        
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to mess with CSS to do this. With https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap you can prevent users from selecting timelots which are already occupied

Comment: I think selectOvelap only works if selectable is set to 'true'.  I tried the boolean and function for selectOverlap and it still allowed me to click in empty area.  However, I have selectable set to 'false' as I don't want users to click-drag event creation.

Comment: If `selectable` is false then what are you using to allow users to click? Don't use dateClick, because it's inflexible! Use `select`, but then use the various options and/or your own custom code to control where, and what, and how much users can select. Otherwise, you can't really fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

Or setting up width and height with calc. For example:

```
width: calc(100% + 8%);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've isolated the responsible CSS.  Overriding .fc-event adjusts the padding

Default:

```
 .fc-event {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: move;
    font-size: .8125rem;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Override:

```
.fc-event {
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
}
```